# Alexa CBT Test: Failed Test due to DeepQuery=True

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

My colleagues and I have been working to fix a reported issue on our Amazon Alexa CBT Test regarding the value “DeepQuery=true”.

Our code has been modified, so that every state change is reported automatically and all the used interfaces have the properties “proactivelyReported” and “retrievable” set to true.

As has been suggested by the WWA-Support we used the Smart Home Debugger of the Developer Console to validate the ReportEvents (e.g. Discovery or ChangeReport) and we checked the state of our device on the “View Device State” page (both pages are referenced on: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/debug-your-smart-home-skill.html).

For debugging purposes we scaled our device capabilities down to just the PowerController. The AddOrUpdateReport of Alexa.Discovery looks to our eyes now exactly as expected/documented. Same goes for the ChangeReport, which we proactively send right after the AddOrUpdateReport (Two sample-Reports for both are provided at the end).
Unfortunately we are still faced with the issue, that “DeepQuery=true” on the “View Device State” page.

If we set the interface property “retrievable” to false, “DeepQuery=false”, but the Alexa-App does not retain the current state of the device. In this configuration the Alexa-App can only be used to send commands, which unfortunately will lead to other test cases to fail.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
How can we set “proactivelyReported” and “retrievable” to true and have “DeepQuery=false”?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will gladly provide more informations if needed.

**Sample AddOrUpdateReport from Smart Home Debugger**

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
        "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
        "messageId": "05b030fb-6393-4ae0-80d0-47fc27876f0e"
    },
    "payload": {
        "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.055ca62d-3cf8-4f51-a683-9a98b36f4637",
        "timestamp": "2021-09-09T13:28:21.629Z",
        "dialogRequestId": null,
        "skillRequestId": null,
        "type": "SmartHomeAddOrUpdateReportSuccess",
        "content": {
            "addOrUpdateReport": {
                "event": {
                    "header": {
                        "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
                        "name": "AddOrUpdateReport",
                        "messageId": "2458b969-7c3e-47e2-ab0b-6e13a999be76",
                        "payloadVersion": "3"
                    },
                    "payload": {
                        "endpoints": [
                            {
                                "manufacturerName": "Our Company Name",
                                "description": "Our Product Name",
                                "endpointId": "device--cb12b420-1171-11ec-81f3-cb34e87ea438",
                                "friendlyName": "Lampe 1",
                                "capabilities": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                                        "version": "3",
                                        "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "supported": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "powerState"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "proactivelyReported": true,
                                            "retrievable": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                                        "interface": "Alexa",
                                        "version": "3"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "displayCategories": [
                                    "LIGHT"
                                ],
                                "connections": [],
                                "relationships": {},
                                "cookie": {}
                            }
                        ],
                        "scope": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample ChangeReport from Smart Home Debugger**

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
        "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
        "messageId": "194a96a1-6747-46ba-8751-5c9ef715fd34"
    },
    "payload": {
        "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.055ca62d-3cf8-4f51-a683-9a98b36f4637",
        "timestamp": "2021-09-09T13:28:23.227Z",
        "dialogRequestId": null,
        "skillRequestId": null,
        "type": "SmartHomeChangeReportSuccess",
        "content": {
            "changeReport": {
                "event": {
                    "header": {
                        "namespace": "Alexa",
                        "name": "ChangeReport",
                        "messageId": "8972e386-9622-40e6-85e7-1a7d81c79c8a",
                        "payloadVersion": "3"
                    },
                    "endpoint": {
                        "scope": null,
                        "endpointId": "device--cb12b420-1171-11ec-81f3-cb34e87ea438"
                    },
                    "payload": {
                        "change": {
                            "cause": {
                                "type": "APP_INTERACTION"
                            },
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                                    "name": "powerState",
                                    "value": "ON",
                                    "timeOfSample": "2021-09-09T13:28:18.088Z",
                                    "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 500
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "context": {
                    "properties": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also recommend you to post on the amazon developer forum for alexa. You might get an answer faster about your specific topic > https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/topics/27353/alexa.html

Comment: Thanks Mathieu. I now posted the same question on the [amazon developer forum](https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/241970/alexa-cbt-test-failed-test-due-to-deepquerytrue.html)